# Get URL variable for text field - How to replace %20 with " "?

Tags: javascript

Using JS to get a variable from URL and populate a text box with a first name.

Code below works well, but if the variable has spaces it will insert %20 in the text box. Looking for a way to replace "%20" with " ".

Example:  link.com/?fn=Mary%20Ellen

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populatefirst() { 
var varSection = window.location.search.substr(1);
var varArray = varSection.split("&");
for(var v=0; v<varArray.length; v++) { 
    var keyValueArray = varArray[v].split("="); 
    if(keyValueArray[0]=="fn") { 
        varValue=keyValueArray[1]; 
        document.getElementById("first_name").value=varValue; 
        break;
        } 
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decodeURIComponent("%20")` results in `" "`

Comment: Where to place? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populatefirst() { 
var varSection = window.location.search.substr(1);
var varArray = varSection.split("&");
for(var v=0; v<varArray.length; v++) { 
    var keyValueArray = varArray[v].split("="); 
    if(keyValueArray[0]=="fn") { 
        varValue=keyValueArray[1]; 
        document.getElementById("first_name").value = decodeURIComponent(varValue); 
        break;
        } 
    }
}
</script>
```